# multiple nested navigation properties EF ?

Tags: entity-framework

i have in my database a **User** has list of **Subscriptions**, each subscription has a **Category**, each category has list of **Paths**, each path has list of **Articles** ?

## Model

```
class User {
  ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions;
}
class Subscription {
   Category category;
}
class Category {
   ICollection<Path> paths;
}
class Path{
   ICollection<Article> Articles;
}
```

my question

## How to retrieve all Articles for a specific user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of `Select` and `SelectMany` statements, you are able to traverse your entities and find the collection you need:

```
var allUserArticles = myUser.Subscriptions
    .Select(sub => sub.Category) //take the category from each subscription
    .SelectMany(cat => cat.Paths) //Take each path from each category, put them in a single list
    .SelectMany(path => path.Articles) //Take each article from each path, put them in a single list
    .ToList();
```

Note that if these entities need to be loaded from your database, that EF either needs to implement eager loading, or you have to make sure that all needed related entities are retrieved before running the above statement. Unexpected nulls can cause your output to be incorrect.

However, I have no info on this as it is missing from the question, so I can't know your specific case.

Comment: no im not implementing eager loading, do i have to use Include before these selects ?? db.Users.Include("Subscriptions.Category.Paths.Articles").First().Subscriptions
    .Select(sub => sub.Category)
    .SelectMany(cat => cat.Paths) 
    .SelectMany(path => path.Articles)
    .ToList();

another question does these select runs in SQL server or they run after that results in memory ??

Comment: Yes. It wouldn't do it exactly like that in a single line, but I assume you've put that as a quick example. Generally, you'll want to use Include to make sure everything is loaded, then use the Select statement like above.

Comment: Extra note: Don't worry about using multiple lines for this, if you are connecting to a database, the query will only be run when you actually want to access the instance. In this case, it means that LINQ will run the compiled query at the `ToList()` call, not before it. Generally, the query will be run the first time you actually try getting one of the Article objects.