# EntityFramework: Discrepency between Includes with Navigation Property vs. Includes with Select?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This is more of a syntax question than an actual bug or error, as I finally got what I wanted working. But I want to understand and perhaps improve upon my current solution.

### Schema

Let's assume I have a `Users` table, with a one-to-many relationship to a table `Posts`, and a further one-to-one relationship table of `Authors` - one for each `Post`.

I want to write a custom repository function to get all `Users`, with all `Posts`, with each `Author` per `Post`.

### Attempt #1 (Doesn't Work)

I thought I could do something like:

```cs
public IQueryable<User> GetUsersWithPostsAndAuthors()
{
    var query = GetAll();

    // include all details on user object
    return query
        .Include(user => user.Posts.Select(x => x.Author));
}
```

it doesn't seem to include the `Author` entity. Actually, I was getting the following error:

```
Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.
```

### Attempt #2 (Also Doesn't Work)

Then I thought that maybe those `Posts` need to be in the query first, so I tried this:

```cs
public IQueryable<User> GetUsersWithPostsAndAuthors()
{
    var query = GetAll();

    // include all details on user object
    return query
        .Include(user => user.Posts)
        .Include(user => user.Posts.Select(x => x.Author)
}
```

Unfortunately, I got the same error:

```
Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.
```

### Attempt #3 (Works!)

However, if I use the version of `Include` where you can provide a `string navigationPropertyPath` (which actually I don't like since it's just a hardcoded string), with something like this:

```cs
public IQueryable<User> GetUsersWithPostsAndAuthors()
{
    var query = GetAll();

    // include all details on user object
    return query
        .Include(user => user.Posts)
        .Include("Posts.Author");
}
```

The query works as expected!

What is going on here? I thought the `Select` projection would do the same as `Include`. (And there seem to be some answers on Stackoverflow suggesting that.)

More importantly, is there a way to accomplish what I want without hardcoding the `Posts.Author` in the `Include` call? I'd like to have static type checks here.

Comment: `query.Include(user => user.Posts).ThenInclude(post => post.Author)` is what you are looking for. You can find this and a lot more detailed documentation at Microsoft Docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is going on here?

No offense, but nothing more than not quite understanding what `Include` is for. It's only for including navigation properties, not for projections.

The syntax is quite clear:

- `Include` for navigation properties off of the root of the query:

  ```cs
  .Include(user => user.Posts)
  ```
- `ThenInclude` for navigation properties off of included navigation properties:

  ```cs
  .Include(user => user.Posts).ThenInclude(p => p.Author)
  ```

The latter example is equivalent to `.Include("Posts.Author")`, but the lambda syntax is preferred because of compile-time checking. In the old EF6 version there was no `ThenInclude` and the syntax for including more levels was as you wrote: `.Include(user => user.Posts.Select(x => x.Author))`.

A projection is a `Select` in the LINQ query, not inside an `Include` statement. For example:

```cs
return query.Select(u => new { u.Id, u.Name });
```

Projections and `Includes` exclude one another. In the projection there's nothing in which a navigation property can be included. A query like:

```cs
return query
    .Include(u => u.Posts)
    .Select(u => new 
    {
        u.Id, 
        u.Name,
        Posts = u.Posts.Select(p => p.Title)
    });
```

will completely ignore the `Include`. There's no trace of it in the generated SQL: only `Post.Title` will be queried, not all `Post` fields, as an `Include` would do.

Comment: The usage of `Select` might indicate they are coming from EF6 and unaware of `ThenInclude` replacement.

Comment: @fullStackChris Just curious, could you show some examples of these "some answers" you refer to? I often notice that this is a confusing area indeed. I wrote more on this area in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147681/861716).

Comment: Ah, I was totally unaware of `ThenInclude`! Very nice! Here's two posts that led me astray, though I realize the original questions for them are a bit different than what I wanted (or maybe not?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469481/multiple-nested-navigation-properties-ef and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120039/how-to-include-nested-child-entity-in-linq

Comment: @fullStackChris These posts are for the EF6 ("classic" EF) which is different from EF Core. EF6 used (and still uses) the `Select` *syntax* to resolve the compile time lambda for including property of element of collection. EF Core simply introduced and uses a special method `ThenInclude` for solving the same syntax problem.

Comment: @fullStackChris One comment goes *Generally, you'll want to use Include to make sure everything is loaded, then use the Select statement like above.* Although it's not clear which Select they refer to, what I often see it that people think they have to sort of "declare" the navigation properties they're gonna use in a projection by adding `Include` statement earlier in the LINQ statement. That's a far too common misconception.